# Como usar Regex em rotas do ruby on rails?

Tags: regex, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Algumas frameworks assim como o `express`, permitem que o usuario use expressão regular (`regex`) para a criação das rotas das páginas.

Tem alguma maneira de usar expressão regular nas rotas do rails para quando não for a rota que eu quero o sistema redireciona para outra action do controller?

Ex:

```rb
get /(user|adm)/ => "controller#action"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As rotas do `Ruby on rails` não aceitam `Regex` mas tem como usar em uma variável passada por parametro na url e tratar com uma expressão para sua finalidade.

```rb
get ":path" => "controller#action", constraints: { path: /(user|adm)/ }
get ":path" => "controller#action_error", constraints: { path: /.+/ }
```

Com isso qualquer rota que seja diferente das palavras `user` e `adm` será chamada a rota `action_error`.